# Is there a way to retrieve Twitter statuses based on a list of status id:s

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm currently trying to get a set of statuses based on a long list (>50k) of Twitter status id:s. Currently I'm using Java with twitter4j. I would really like to avoid making individual calls for each id if possible, but any approach that is faster than my current code (see below) would be much appreciated.

```
public class TweetById {
private static String consumerKey = ...;
private static String consumerSecret = ...;
private static String accessToken = ...;
private static String accessTokenSecret = ...;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // connect to Twitter
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret);

    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

    String[] ids = new String[]{"327664925705109505", "327665399644696576","327666368516341761"};
    for(String id : ids){
        try {
            Status status = twitter.showStatus(Long.parseLong(id));
            System.out.println("Time: " + status.getCreatedAt() + ": " + status.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Edit:
I have now attempted to use the asynchronous methods in twitter4j but I can't seem to get it working. Is there something I'm missing?

```
public class TweetById {
private static String consumerKey = ...;
private static String consumerSecret = ...;
private static String accessToken = ...;
private static String accessTokenSecret = ...;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // connect to Twitter
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret);

    // The factory instance is re-useable and thread safe.
    AsyncTwitterFactory factory = new AsyncTwitterFactory(cb.build());
    AsyncTwitter asyncTwitter = factory.getInstance();
    asyncTwitter.addListener(new TwitterAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void gotShowStatus(Status status) {
            System.out.println("Time: " + status.getCreatedAt() + ": " + status.getText());
        }
    });

    String[] ids = new String[] { "327664925705109505", "327665399644696576", "327666368516341761" };
    for (String id : ids) {
        asyncTwitter.showStatus(Long.parseLong(id));
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal but you can use [`lookup(long[] ids)`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TweetsResources.html#lookup-long:A-) to retrieve up to 100 statues at time.

Comment: Thanks, that speeds things up considerably. If I could only combine that with the asynchronous call it would be great.